# Is it possible to install MongoDB in separated gear of OpenShift?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift

I'd like to create a Nodejs app with MongoDB in OpenShift for free. Because the size of the gear is 1G so that I'm wondering if possible to create NodeJs app in one gear and MongoDB in another so that I'm able to have more storage. Is this even possible? And how if possible? Thanks.

**P.S**: Or is it possible to assign all 3GB space and 1.5GB RAM to one gear?

Comment: After installation of nodejs, the space used about 400MB already. Is it possible to remove nodejs and only use MongoDB in one gear?